# wp_enqueue_style Not working after upgrade

Tags: php, wordpress

Can't get the stylesheet to show in end results.

Sorry, the stack overflow does not work.

The function runs.  Echoing after Main.min.css works, but the script is not showing.  Im not sure why.  Everything I try does not work.

```
wp_enqueue_style('style.css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), NAKED_VERSION, FALSE);
//wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap.min.css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css', array(), NAKED_VERSION, FALSE);
wp_enqueue_style('slick.min.css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css', array(''), NAKED_VERSION, FALSE);
wp_enqueue_style('slick-theme.min.css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css', array('slick.min.css'), NAKED_VERSION, FALSE);
wp_enqueue_style('main-site.min.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/stylesheets/main.min.css', array('slick-theme.min.css'), NAKED_VERSION, FALSE);
```

I want main.min.css at the path specified to show up as designed.  Wordpress 5 broke this.  The site no longer shows correctly.

Edit (added):
How do I get my site to work as it was before the upgrade, given that the above statements clearly indicate the problem and that the display is not correct?

Resolution Found (edit):
I removed the dependency string from the array and found that caused it to load.  I then simplified the dependency string (found above) to not include the extensions. I also removed the '' from the array in the 'slick.min.css'. This caused it to resolve.

Comment: You should try actually asking a question.

Comment: I did.  The Main.min.css does not output as expected.  The CSS is not included as it was before the Wordpress update.  I don't know why.

Comment: No, you made statements. You didn't ask a question. Have you looked at your console output for errors?

Comment: I'm sorry... here...

"How do I get my site to work as it was before the upgrade, given that the above statements clearly indicate the problem and that the display is not correct?"

No errors.  Code runs as expected.

Comment: <?php wp_footer(); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?> are also included in the code.

I see no indication in WP upgrade notes about any changes to the style sheet enque

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you added wp_head() and wp_footer() in header.php and footer.php?
Verify that the wp_enqueue_style should work then.

Comment: Yes, Im sure.  This is weird.  I was thinking cause it failed to have the register.  But the enqueue alone with this param config should work.  I tried it with a register with no hope.  I was wondering if it was the Dependency.  Its set to 'slick-theme.min.css' but I think its accurate.  I don't see any spelling problems!

Comment: I removed the dependency from the array.  Leaving it blank.  That had caused it to suddenly show on the results.  I simplified the dependencies wtih none of the extensions and this seems to have resolved the issue.  Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i can confirm. I had the same problem after an update from 5.0.0 to 5.0.2.

Removing the dependencies did fix the issue for me also.

before:

```
wp_enqueue_style(
  'nuk.editor',
  plugins_url($editorStylePath, __FILE__),
  [  'wp-blocks' ],
  filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . $editorStylePath )
);
```

after:

```
wp_enqueue_style(
  'nuk.editor',
  plugins_url($editorStylePath, __FILE__),
  [],
  filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . $editorStylePath )
);
```